# Modify Associated Records with Join Table Attributes (In Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

I have a fairly straight forward `has_many :through` association setup.

```
class Store
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :products, through: :store_products
end
```

So I can easily do things like `@store.products` and get back the associated products.

I would like to add additional attributes to the join model which will allow me to override specific values on the products returned - `price` for example.  A `@product` has a `price` defined already, but I would like the ability to override that value (automatically) on a `@store` basis.  If the `price` attribute on the join model is `nil`, use the `price` set on the `product` - if not, use the `price` set on the join model.

Multiple stores can have the same product, but with different prices for each.

I don't want to change the functionality of `@store.products` - it should still return an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, but the products in that result will differ based on the `store`

Comment: I understand that yo uwant `@store.products[0].price` to return the correct price. But what does `@store.products[0].update(price: 10)` do? does it update the join table price or the original product price?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. What have you considered? What have you tried? What specific problems have you run into?

Comment: @jvillian I suggest you post an answer with at least one way to do it. I don't think the question should be closed, it is clear and specific and is worth answering.

Comment: @TamerShlash - Thank you for the suggestion. I am happy to help, but based on the information provided it would appear that there was [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) made to satisfy the stated aspiration/requirement.

Comment: @jvillian I don't want to start an argument, but the "no attempt" link you provided is not from SO or the meta. If providing no attempt _alone_ is enough reason to close a question, then it would be an option in the close vote popup. But it is not. The question, imho, is clear and specific, and should be answerable if there is a solution. It doesn't appear to be too broad by any means for me.